# Is there a way to glob through multiple directories?

Tags: python-3.x, glob

I'm looking for a way to glob through multiple directories and perform an action on the files contained in for instance 3 directories?

Say, I have the following code:

```
example_var = ["/Library/name_of_a_folder/*", "/Users/$USER/again_some_name/*", "/System/Library/third_folder/*"
```

Obviously replacing multipleglob with a function or method that allows me to glob through multiple filepaths. In saying so, I cannot use any dependencies so I would prefer to do this with a standard library function/method.

The goal of this is to later iterate through these multiple dirs in one statement:

```
for i in example_var:
[...]
```

Comment: Why don't you glob on ``'/path_?/*'``? Is the difference between paths always just one character?

Comment: To clarify: I'm looking for certain items which relate to a certain service and these items are located in 3 different locations, hence why I would like to glob through these 3 locations and save them in a var.

Comment: I'm afraid that does not clarify much - to the contrary, the text says 2 directories, the code has 4 directories, the comment says 3 locations. The code shows defining 2 variables, the comment says defining 1 variable. The code implies these paths are similar, the comment seems to imply otherwise. Can you please [edit] *your question* to clarify what you are trying to do, what have tried so far, and what specific technical problem you have encountered and need help with? Please see the [mcve] and [ask] pages how to best help us help you.

Comment: My apologies, I edited the post

Comment: To repeat my initial question with a slight change: Why don't you glob on ``"/Library/example_folder_?/*"``? Why don't you do a separate glob for each directory?

Comment: I edited my post to show that the paths are not equal, good point you made there. Concerning your last comment, I'm doing this for quite some paths so it would save me a lot of code if I could do this with a "multiglob" instead of glob-ing through each seperate dir

Comment: I was not able to find any such library function.  The usual approach seems to be to write your own, as MisterMiyagi's question suggests.  If you have a lot of directories in a list, it shouldn't take a lot of code to iterate through the list and compile a list of file paths.